# collectionfs generate download url

Tags: html, image, meteor

I am working on a project using meteor and collectionfs.

I upload files to collectionfs and have a filehandler in place. I can use the
{{cfsFileUrl "defaultFilehandler"}}

Handlebar Helper to display the url where the image is saved, but I can't download images from this URL.

When I copy it into my browser:

```
localhost:3000/cfs/contacts/Nj3WzrBKhqd9Mc9NP_defaultHandler.png
```

meteor routes me to the meteor page ( as if i had writen localhost:3000 )

Ultimately I would like to achieve two things:

1st

display the image using an html tag:

```
<img src=??? alt="your image" />
```

2nd
I would like to make sure that the user is allowed to see this image.

Having the 'download-url' is not sufficient security for me.

In order to get to the point i went through the normal tutorial from collectionFS:

client js

```
ContactsFS = new CollectionFS('contacts', { autopublish: false });

Deps.autorun(function() {
    Meteor.subscribe('myContactsFiles');
});

Template.queueControl.events({
    'change .fileUploader': function (e) {
        var files = e.target.files;
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            ContactsFS.storeFile(f);
        }
    }
});
```

server js

```
ContactsFS = new CollectionFS('contacts', { autopublish: false });

ContactsFS.allow({
    insert: function(userId, file) { 
        console.log('user'+userId+"file"+JSON.stringify(file));
        console.log("WILL SAVE:"+userId && file.owner === userId );
        return userId && file.owner === userId; 
    },
    update: function(userId, files, fields, modifier) {
        return _.all(files, function (file) {
            return (userId == file.owner);
        });  //EO iterate through files
    },
    remove: function(userId, files) { return false; }
});

Meteor.publish('myContactsFiles', function() {
    if (this.userId) {
        return ContactsFS.find({ owner: this.userId }, { limit: 30 });
    }
});


ContactsFS.fileHandlers({
  default1: function(options) { // Options contains blob and fileRecord — same is expected in return if should be saved on filesytem, can be modified
    return { blob: options.blob, fileRecord: options.fileRecord }; // if no blob then save result in fileHandle (added createdAt)
  }});
```

Comment: Hi, I faced a problem when I tried displaying the image. It showed a broken image icon with this error, "Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html:". Did you face the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer 1:

You can use the updated 0.3.3+ version of collectionFS to publicly make those files accessable, or view them.

```
<img src="{{cfsFileUrl 'default1'}}">
```

where `default1` is the name of the handler function you defined in `ContactsFS.fileHandlers`

Answer 2:

There is no secure solution build into collectionFS as of now, its in the making tho.

Comment: After following your suggestion, the image icon is shown but its broken with this error, "Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html:". Any idea how I should go about fixing this??